# Store date as if they were entered in a specific timezone

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, momentjs

I am using Moment. I need users to enter a date, and make sure that that's always the time for Australia/Perth, regardless of what the browser is set as.
For example, assume the computer is set as Sydney time (which right now is +3 but in winter it's +2). I want the user to enter a date/time, and make sure that that date/time is stored as Perth's time.

Note that *visualising* the correct date isn't an issue (with `moment.tz`). What I am worried about, is the date object creation which would need to happen providing a time, and forcing the browser to pretend that they are in that timezone.

I need this to work regardless of daylight savings etc.

**UPDATE**: this is what I want to achieve:

```
// MY CURRENT TIMEZONE IS SYDNEY, CURRENTLY PERTH + 3 BUT +2 IN SUMMER
// IN PERTH IT's 10:11AM, and *THAT* is the time I am interested in 
// storing, not 13:11:58
var d = new Date()
// => Wed Nov 28 2018 13:11:58 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time)

// NOTE: the date 13:11:58 SYDNEY time. I don't want this.
// I MUST pretend that users entered the date with their timezone
// is in Perth
// So...

// Create a date string that exclude original timezone and includes new timezone
perthDateString = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:ss') + '+0800'
// => "2018-11-28T13:11:58+0800"

// Make a new date object using the tinkered date string 
var newD = new Date(perthDateString)

// Display the date. Note: the time is "wrong" (since it displays
// a time that is 3 hours ahead), but it's actually the correct
// answer since 'd' is meant to be Perth time in the first place
newD
// => Wed Nov 28 2018 16:11:58 GMT+1100 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time)

// Display the date as the Perth time
moment.tz(newD, 'Australia/Perth').toString()
// => "Wed Nov 28 2018 13:11:58 GMT+0800"
```

However:

- in `perthDateString = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:ss') + '+0800'`, I would like to specify `Australia/Perth`, rather than `'+0800'`
- I feel uneasy with dealing with dates by chopping/concatenating strings
- I wonder if EVERY browser will be able to parse the date returned by `.format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:ss') + '+0800'` or if I am going to have surprises -- especially when/if I have a solution so that I use `Australia/Perth` instead

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime . 
getTime() always uses UTC for time representation. For example, a client browser in one timezone, getTime() will be the same as a client browser in any other timezone.

Comment: IMHO you should really consider using times only in UTC (except for display of course).  Sure, store the timezone as well if you need it, but for inter-state (or international) time comparisons, anything except UTC becomes a *rod for your own back*.

Comment: @Kingsley that is already the case. I store dates as UTC on the DB. But, if a user in Sydney writes `12:30`, I actually want to store `15:30`. What I am trying to do, is a way so that I force clients to enter times as if they were in Perth

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer I am not worried about displaying (see post), I am worried about *storing*

Comment: Hmm. One of us is confused. If you are storing the time in UTC, then you are NOT storing either Sydney time (e.g., `12:30`) or Perth time (the equivalent would be `9:30` -- not `15:30`, as you indicated). When displaying the time, the stored UTC time (`1:30`) can be converted to whatever other time zone you want -- which you already know. So, if you are already storing in UTC time, and you already know you need to convert to the appropriate time zone when the time needs to be displayed, then do you actually have a problem?

Comment: Updated the question with code to clarify -- apologies

Comment: To give context: these are times that are stored in UTC, but that must be entered -- and displayed - as if they were entered - and displayed - in Perth, regardless of where they were entered -- or displayed -- in terms of browser/system timezone

Comment: So, it's not "what moment in UTC does this happen?" (which is then translated to different timezones depending on the UTC). It's more about "What date/time did this happen in Perth?" (never ever translating to local times, when inputting nor displaying)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are anywhere in the world (say, Sydney or Tokyo), and the local time is "12:30", but you want to store the same time-of-day ("12:30") as if you were in Perth -- you can use the [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) package together with [moment](https://momentjs.com/).

For example, this snippet will give you a `moment` for "12:30" in Perth:

```js
let x = moment.tz('2019-01-01T12:30:00', 'Australia/Perth')
console.log(x.format());  // Show that it is 12:30 in Perth time
console.log(new Date(x)); // Generate Date for that time
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, yes and YES. YES and YES and THANKS!

Comment: No wonder you have 38.1k points... Trivia: Tokio is very very nearly in the same timezone as Perth eheheheh :D

Comment: Bonus question -- if I may. What if I have `d="2018-01-30"` and `t="18:30"` and want to create this time as if I was in Perth? At the moment I am doing `var d = moment.tz(`${d} ${t}`, 'Australia/Perth')`  but it feels hacky and wrong... help?

Comment: Try: `moment.tz(d, 'Australia/Perth').add(moment.duration(t));`